# how to remove pushpin buttons on bingmap controll in wp7?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have one Bingmap control in wp7. This bingmap contain so many pushpin buttons. And i wants to remove this buttons when click event is fire.
So how to remove this button?

I tryed bellow c# code but its not working

map1.children.remove(pin[i])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a MapLayer and add a pushpin to that MapLayer and then clear the layer before adding the next pushpin.

Don't forget to add that MapLayer  as achild to the map control

Answer (score 1):

I have done it this way:

- XAML: At map control set MapItemsControl. You can bind your pushpin collection over ItemSource in code alter.
- Code behind: to remove all pushpins from Map set ItemSource NULL. That's all.